# webpack-dev-server 4.7.3 Как отключить автоматическое обновление браузера

Tags: webpack-dev-server

Я обновил webpack-dev-server с версии 3 до версии 4.7.3, и теперь каждый раз при изменении и пересборке css/js окно браузера обновляется сразу после фокуса, как избежать такого поведения? Я хотел бы обновить его вручную когда захочу

```
    ...
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    devServer: {
        hot: false,
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        devMiddleware: {
            publicPath: '/',
            stats: 'errors-only',
        },
        static: {
            publicPath: paths.dist,
        },
        allowedHosts: 'all',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        host: process.env.LOCAL_HOST,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

[Посмотри здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797704/how-to-disable-webpack-dev-server-auto-reload)
Для devServer inline: false,
Может и для 4.7.3 тоже норм
[10 особенностей Webpack](https://habr.com/ru/company/plarium/blog/309230/)

```
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    devServer: {
        hot: false,

        inline: false,

        open: true,
        compress: true,
        devMiddleware: {
            publicPath: '/',
            stats: 'errors-only',
        },
        static: {
            publicPath: paths.dist,
        },
        allowedHosts: 'all',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        host: process.env.LOCAL_HOST,
    },
```